# Subscription of few tables in kdb RDB

Tags: kdb

i am running the kdb tickerplant architecture with 1 tick process, 1 RDB process, and 1 HDB process. But tickerplant memory seems to be increasing which denotes slow consumer in this case RDB, so I would like to split the tables between 2 RDB's so inorder me to do that i need to modify the RDB script :

```
/q tick/r.q [host]:port[:usr:pwd] [host]:port[:usr:pwd]
/2008.09.09 .k ->.q

if[not "w"=first string .z.o;system "sleep 1"];

upd:insert;

/ get the ticker plant and history ports, defaults are 5010,5012
.u.x:.z.x,(count .z.x)_(":5010";":5012");


.u.end:{t:tables`.;
    {0!x}each t;
    t@:where `g=attr each t@\:`sym;
    .Q.hdpf[`$":",.u.x 1;`:.;x;`sym];
    @[;`sym;`g#] each t;    
    `account_balances set select by sym, asset from account_balances; 
    .Q.gc[];};

.u.rep:{(.[;();:;].)each x;
    if[null first y;:()];
    -11!y;
    .Q.gc[];
    `account_balances set select by sym, asset from account_balances; 
    `upd set (upsert);
    system "cd ",1_-10_string first reverse y};

/ HARDCODE \cd if other than logdir/db

/ connect to ticker plant for (schema;(logcount;log))
.u.rep .(hopen `$":",.u.x 0)"(.u.sub[`trade;`];`.u `i`L)";
```

So i changed the above RDB script to subscribe to trade table only

```
.u.rep .(hopen `$":",.u.x 0)"(.u.sub[`account_balances;`];`.u `i`L)";
```

But i am getting this error :

```
'type
  [3]  /home/naseef/q/l64/tick/rdb.q:31: .u.rep:{(.[;();:;].)each x;
                                                             ^
 if[null first y;:()];
```

Comment: Have you inspected `x`? It should be a list of `(table;contents)`.

Comment: `account_balances
+`time`sym`asset`locked_balance`available_balance`total_balance`timestamp!(`t..


i put `show x` and the above one is what i am getting

Comment: Try this and see if it works: ```(.u.sub[;`]each (),`account_balances;`.u `i`L)```

Comment: @terrylynch that worked thankyou! what caused error in mine ? can you write an answer here so i can accept it please ?

Comment: Not a solution but an alternative suggestion, have you considered having two RDBs / TPs subscribing to a subset of symbols?

Comment: do you have any articles on this ? @user20349

Comment: @user20349 even if i scale the RDB by sym i still have a problem of end of day operation where HDB wont sync, to all RDB's, but i also tried having 1 HDB per RDB still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments on the original post: the issue here is that the RDB subscription logic assumes the schema will be a *list* of tuples, e.g. it assumes something like this

```
((`tab1;([]col1:`$()));(`tab2;([]colA:`$();col2:()));(`tab3;([]colB:`$())))
```

is returned from the `.u.sub` component of the subscription call

```
"(.u.sub[`;`];`.u `i`L)"
```

In your case however, since you only subscribed to one table `` .u.sub[`trade;`] ``, the schema was returned as a tuple rather than a list of tuples

```
(`trade;([]col1:`$();col2:()))
```

so then the line in `.u.rep` which sets the schema in memory

```
(.[;();:;].)each x
```

didn't work as intended (since it expects to apply to *each* tuple).

My suggestion was to change the subscription call to

```
.u.sub[;`]each (),`trade
```

as this will essentially force the result to be an enlisted tuple

Comment: Hi @terrylynch ! this works but but i am getting type error at 11!y
when quitting the RDB and restarting again. It happens at replay function in .u.rep `11!y`

Comment: I have 2 RDB's 1 RDB subscribes to subset of all tables and 2nd RDB also only subcribes to subset of all tables, this error goes away if i subscribe to all tables,

Comment: Try modifying your upd function to: ```upd:{if[x in tables[];x insert y]};```

Comment: thankyou so much! one last doubt if i do this :  `upd set (upsert);
after the replay it will still set the upd as upsert right ?

Comment: Yes, but `insert` is preferred over `upsert` (it's faster) so unless you have good reason to use `upsert` I would leave it alone

Comment: .u.endofday[]

i triggered manually this in tickerplant and in 1 RDB it hitting this error
'./2024.02.05/withdrawal_statements/.d. OS reports: No such file or directory

here table withdrawal_statements is not in this RDB but its in another RDB, but still get the error, also i have 2 HDB's as well 1 for each RDB

Comment: If you're using `.Q.hdpf` in both RDBs then it's likely that both RDBs are trying to send a command to the HDB to reload the database but one RDB may be sending the reload command before the other RDB is finished writing so the HDB throws that error you see. Not sure of the best way to get around it - one option is to make neither RDB send a reload command to HDB, just have them write to database. You could achieve this by not passing the HDB host:port to the RDB startup command. Have another mechanism to reload HDB independently

Comment: yes to solve this 1 HDB for each RDB right ?

Comment: if both RDB are working on different tables this shouldn't happen too right ?

Comment: I was trying to solve this by having seperate HDB for each RDB, but I failed in this regard too because when you instantiate the tickerplant process you provide the tables schema folder hence it appends all data inside the sym folder only doesnt matter what location you give to the seperate HDB process

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by HDB - are you talking about two HDB *processes* or two HDB *locations*? You only need one HDB process and you also only need one HDB location. You can still have two RDB processes which both write to the one HDB location, but the single HDB process should only be refreshed once after all tables are written by both RDBs